# What's the search area for a meteorite that lands in the ocean and sinks to the ocean floor?

Tags: science-based, ocean

A meteorite survives entry and lands in the ocean. For various reasons, people would like to recover the core of this meteorite.

Observers of the landing are able to narrow down the location of its impact with the surface to an area of approximately 50 km<sup>2</sup> (about 19.3 mi<sup>2</sup>). The ocean in that area is a bit deeper than usual but not abyssal trench depths, 5000 to 6000 meters (16,400 to 19,700 feet). For comparison, the wreck of the Titanic is about 3,800 meters (12,500 feet) deep.

Assuming Earth-like oceans and the necessary magic for an ocean floor search is available, *roughly* how large would the search area on the ocean floor be, given that ocean currents at various depths could have moved the meteorite in various directions as it sank? Available ocean current charting is at a level roughly equivalent to Earth in 1800.

Assume the meteorite has a standard nickel-iron composition, and impacted at an angle of entry greater than 45 degrees but less than 80 degrees. Assume that the largest part of the meteorite to survive the impact with the surface (the piece that we are interested in) is roughly spherical and approximately 1 meter in diameter.

Un-specified: Assume a realistic size and velocity for the meteorite before impact with the surface that will not generate major tidal waves or other disasters and will produce a core or largest surviving chunk of around 1 meter diameter as mentioned.

Worst case (that is, largest) search area estimates are preferred.

Comment: Is the size, angle of entry, speed of entry, or composition known?

Comment: In addition to the comment from @Nosajimiki we would need to know what the interaction of it hitting the water was like. E.g. did it stay relatively intact because it was super dense or did it shatter into pieces?

Comment: satellite tracking should be able to narrow it down by a lot more. big meteorites like that garner a lot of attention.

Comment: @John - I am skeptical of that assertion.   We have enough trouble determining where larger (in terms of volume) pieces of space junk have impacted.  Most metorite-hunters searching for the shards of a meteorite in a land impact are dependent on ground-level weather radar, not satellite tracking.

Comment: @jdunlop except this is among the largest meteorites on earth, large and generating enough heat to be picked up by missile tracking. Although this would depend on location.

Comment: Technically, having a meteorite slow down to terminal velocity is kind of abstract, or requires greatly increased atmospheric density. If your meteorite was initially 2 meters across, and had a delta-V with Earth of no less than 3 km/s (I'm not sure if this slow is even possible as we are talking about more than satellite descent), it won't succeed to slow down to terminal velocity at such reentry angle. It would need about 100x denser (and no less than 2x higher) atmosphere to slow that thing down before impact to the ocean.

Comment: @Vesper What would be a more realistic speed that wouldn't also cause catastrophic tidal waves or anything?

Comment: I'd say more realistic speed would be about 3 km/s at impact, this would not cause any tidal waves even if the meteorite would be 10 meters in diameter, as you have your ocean deep enough. I assume that exactly this initial size would allow to get shattered by water contact and leave your desired 1m core. But with such an impact speed the slowdown physics would get different, I don't have the data to say whether the remains of that meteorite would reach the bottom before slowing to dozens of m/s.

Comment: OP said "*presumably* at terminal velocity".  I don't believe that such a meteorite weighing around 4.3t would be moving that slowly when it hits the water.

Comment: @MontyWild - 3.7tonnes, not 37 tonnes.  It's only a metre across.

Comment: @jdunlop 4.3t... apparently I don't know how to use a calculator...

Comment: @jdunlop anyway, slowing 3.7 tons, 4.3 tons or 3.7 tonnes (imperial) from reentry speeds of no less than 3 km/s (and likely average speed of meteorites at Karman line is greater) requires converting about 18 MJ of kinetic energy only by about 160 km of atmosphere, and over 100 seconds at most. Atmospheric drag would not be enough, while the calc says it will exert 2.4MN/m^2 at the ground level, for Earth's atmosphere, the integral acceleration over the entire course could only lower the initial velocity by about 3 seconds' worth of this force, or about 1500 m/s, less if initial speed is higher

Comment: And impacting the water at 1500 m/s would probably cause too much energy to turn into heat, as water would then cause 450 MN "raw" slowing force, not counting supersonic, shockwave or surface effects of collision. This would slow the orb in about half a second down to terminal velocity in water (as calculated, 14 m/s) but releasing about 5 GJ of energy in the process - that would be enough to shatter the already heated meteorite into fragments, so the search would be in vain, hmm.

Comment: Finding a 1 meter sized object on the ocean floor can be a very difficult job. Look at the difficulty in finding airplanes that crashed in the ocean. Here is the account of finding a missing H-bomb on the ocean floor. It took weeks and luck. https://www.whoi.edu/oceanus/feature/little-alvin-and-the-lost-h-bomb/

Comment: The Titanic was found by looking for the debris trail. A debris trail is much larger than the ship. In this case, you don't have a debris trail (unless that 1 meter rock shattered). 50 square km is 50,000,000 times the size of what you are looking for. What if it landed on the side of a canyon triggering an underwater landslide burying it? The search would be very challenging.

Answer (score 7):

This is basically a physics question.  First, the terminal velocity of a sinking object is expressed by
$v_t = \sqrt{\frac{2(m - p_fV)g}{Cp_fA}}$

Where $m$ is the mass of the object, $p_f$ is the density of the fluid, $V$ is the volume of the object, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity, $C$ is the drag coefficient, and $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the object.

So if we assume a density of ~8000$kg/m^3$ (nice round number and nickel-iron blend), and a 1$m$ sphere, the $(m-p_fV)$ expression evaluates to $\frac{4}{3}\pi (0.5m)^3 \times 7000kg \approx 3700kg$.

$p_f$ is $1000kg/m^3$

$C$ is 0.47 (for a sphere)

$g$ is $9.8m/s^2$

and $A$ is $\approx 0.785m^2$

So terminal velocity would be about 14 m/s.

If we assume the shallower end of your projected depth, 5000m, that means the meteorite would take about six minutes (358 seconds) to sink.

Ocean currents [can be as rapid as 4m/s](https://www.britannica.com/science/ocean-current).  If we assume the worst-case, that such a vigorous current is applied to the meteorite consistently in any given direction as it sinks, then that generates a radius of 4 * 358 $\approx$ $1.5km$ around a straight line down from its point of impact.

If we assume the original $50km^2$ approximate impact space is circular, that gives us a radius of $\approx 4km$.  Again assuming worst-case, the drift would expand that radius by 1.5km uniformly.

$\pi \times (5.5km)^2 \approx 95km^2$, or about twice your original search area.

---

Note: A bunch of assumptions were made in the course of this calculation (Earth gravity, ocean is made of water and not some other liquid, density of the meteorite) and a bunch of rounding was done because it's easier.  You can tweak any number of these values for the world in which this occurs.

Comment: "First, we assume a spherical cow..."

Comment: keep in mind a meteorite of that size is going to plow through a lot of water ballistically before it starts to sink. meteorite are falling at a LOT more than terminal velocity.

Comment: @John - the OP indicated that the meteorite is falling at terminal velocity by the moment of impact.  And the incompressibility of water decelerates things _quickly_.  A small meteorite is likely to be well, _well_ below orbital velocities by the time it hits the ground - most metorites hit at well under the speed of sound.

Comment: @John - Assuming the upper bound of typical non-micro-meteorite impact (~180m/s), and neglecting the impact of surface tension (substantial), the decelerative force exerted on the meteorite is about six _million_ Newtons.  Obviously that drops off as the meteorite slows down, but the initial deceleration would be about 1600 m/s/s.  So it should drop to terminal velocity in water on the order of _seconds_, during which it would not be expected to penetrate any appreciable fraction of the 5km sink.

Comment: Sorry missed the OP's mention of terminal velocity, that makes it a very strange meteorite. Keep in mind the largest part is a meter across after landing, that makes the initial meteorite much larger, 1 meter across is already among the top 10-20 largest meteorites on earth.

Comment: @jdunlop what speed is assumed for the meteorite at depth=0? I really think that a meteorite cannot get slowed to freefall terminal velocity by atmospheric drag if it's that large, especially at the given reentry angle of more than 45 degrees. Your calculations are good for a rock thrown off a cliff into the depth, but a meteorite should impact at about 100x the velocity (no less than 3 km/s, and upper bound is estimated to be 60 km/s for retrograde orbit asteroid. The latter would not survive the impact no matter how big it is)

Comment: @Vesper - first, no small meteor is going to make it to ground level at 3 km/s.  Second, as already commented to John, the OP specified _terminal velocity_ at impact, and the survival of the meteorite.  With those assumptions, my calculations hold.

Comment: Keep in mind that meteorologists generally know the approximate direction speed and depth of subsurface currents in most of the ocean; so, you don't need to know the maximum speed of a current, but precision of how well we known these currents.

Comment: Using [Impact Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth) approximations, the meteorite would make it less than 10m below the surface of the water before it was at the terminal velocity of 14m/s.